# Where to put sql2java.properties in Java web application?

Tags: java, properties, sql2java

I'm new to Java development.

I have a web site and it builds very well, but it doesn't copy the file `sql2java.properties`. Also, I get an SQL error connection, I think is because this file does not exist in files.

Where do I put the file `sql2java.properties`?

My path is:

```
+build
   +empyt
   +web
       +admin
       +files
       index.html
       +META-INF
       +site
       +WEB-INF
```

Comment: `WEB-INF/classes` or `META-INF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the example project at http://sql2java.sourceforge.net/example.html -- it should give you an idea of how you need to configure your application.